# Datatable - without bootstrap - overflow solution

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

This is the mobile view of the page I am working on. 
Can somebody tell me how I can restrict datatable to the parent container or define media queries to restrict its width on small screen devices? 
Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP7fD.jpg

Comment: If you can create `JSFiddle` of your problem it will be easy to give you solution.

Comment: I fail to see how an image can be considered as evidence or elaboration on a programming Q&A site. How on earth should anyone be able to suggest corrections in your code based on a blurred screenshot? How should it help future visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have too add overflow:hidden and it does it. By giving width to parent div.